# dispatch action triggering, but redux store not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers, react-redux

Currently in my React-Redux app, I would like to use React to set the state of show to either false, or true. When set to true, the app will initialize. (There are multiple components, so it would make sense to do this using react/redux.)

However, my current issue is that even though I have connected my app using react redux, and my store using provider, the dispatch action will be called, without updating the store(I am using redux dev tools to double check, as well as in app testing).

I have attached the code I feel is relevant, however, the entire code base is available as a branch specifically made for this question [here](https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/newRub/tree/stackoverflow-react-redux/app/scripts). I have spent quite sometime on this(actually an understatement) and any contributions would be greatly appreciated.

**Component Relevant Code**

```
hideBlock(){
const{dispatch} = this.props;
dispatch(hideBlock);
}

return(
  <div className = "works">
    <button id="show-block" type="button" className="show-hide-button" onClick={this.showBlock}>show</button>
    <button id="hide-block" type="button" className="show-hide-button" onClick={this.hideBlock}>Hide</button>
  </div>
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {environment} = state;
  return{
    environment
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form);
```

**Action**

```
import * as types from "../constants/ActionTypes";

export function showBlock(show) {
   return {
      type: types.SHOW,
      show: true
   };
}

export function hideBlock(hide) {
   return {
      type: types.HIDE,
      show: false
   };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import * as types from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const initialState = {
   show: false
};

export default function environment(state = initialState, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case types.HIDE:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              type: types.HIDE
          });
      case types.SHOW:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              type: types.SHOW
          });
      default:
          return state;
    } 
 }
```

Thank you, and once again any help is very much so appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I asked a co-worker for help and it turns out that I was returning my action as an object instead of a function. So, for instance, changing the following code:

```
hideBlock(){
  const{dispatch} = this.props;
  dispatch(hideBlock);
}
```

to

```
hideBlock(){
  const{dispatch} = this.props;
  //change hideBlock to hideBlock()
  dispatch(hideBlock());
}
```

solved the issue. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: Yes, the action is an object with a `type` property, not a function. Which is why you can create more abstract/concise functions to manufacture redux/flux actions, all that matters is the action you get out at the end.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `state.show` is set in initialState but never modified in any of the cases inside the reducer. The action has `show: true`, but the reducer never uses this to update the state.

Here's a simplified reducer that updates `state.show` based on the action's `show` field:

```
export default function environment(state = initialState, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case types.HIDE:
      case types.SHOW:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              show: action.show
          });
      default:
          return state;
    } 
 }
```

Alternatively, because `action.show` and `action.type` have the same data, you could remove `show` from the actions and rely on the action type:

```
export default function environment(state = initialState, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case types.HIDE:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              show: false
          });
      case types.SHOW:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
              show: true
          });
      default:
          return state;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Kevan, if you would be kind enough to include a code snippet as to how the reducer should look, to reflect this comment, it would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Edited to add reducer snippets.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not addressing the error in the question, which is that an action is an object and not a function.

Comment: Whoops, confusion between action creators and actions strikes again.